# Where should a Python package store compiled libraries?

Tags: python, package, setuptools, local-shared-object

I downloaded an API from some external hardware. Its Python bindings are a bunch of `.py` files and an `.so`, like so:

```
aa.py
bb.py
cc.pp
api.so
```

I want to install that as a Python package so that they do not clutter up my main program directory. Can I arrange the directory tree like this?

```
hardware_api/
├── hardware_api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── aa.py
│   ├── api.so
│   ├── bb.py
│   └── cc.py
└── setup.py
```

Then install it with `pip install .`? The most important file here is `api.so`. Will an `import hardware_api` be able to load `api.so` properly, given its location? Or should `api.so` be in some other location? Is there some special command I need to write in `setup.py`?

### Update 2014-01-29

I tried doing the above, but only the `.py` files get installed. The `.so` file is ignored.

Comment: anywhere in `sys.path` would do i guess?

Comment: @Torxed, I would like it to be atomically installed with the whole package.